# UIWebView shows a black screen with no content

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uikit

I've created a UIWebView from the IB and subclassed it to my needs. Somewhere inside my app I'm using the following code:

```
_mainWebView = nil;
_mainWebView = [[MyWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
_mainWebView.delegate = self;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_mainWebView loadRequest:request]; 
NSLog(@"WebView: %@", _mainWebView); //->> WebView: <MyWebView: 0x15403000; baseClass = UIWebView; frame = (0 0; 320 548); layer = <CALayer: 0x1544dac0>>
```

Which gives me a black screen with no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely because you're setting _mainWebView to nil. This pretty much means you "unplug" the outlet you hooked up from Interface Builder. So the web view you're configuring in this code isn't connected to the screen at all. There are two options you can choose from:

1) Use Interface Builder, connect the outlets, and remove the first two lines of code in the snippet above.

2) Remove the web view from Interface Builder, remove the first line of code in the snippet above, and add `[self.view addSubview:_mainWebView];` before you load the request.

By the way, I believe [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is not to be subclassed, at least in an App Store release. It could be potentially breakable in future iOS's...

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Worth emphasizing: The MyWebView created in the code in the question and the web view that exists in the nib are *two different views*. The questioner replaces the view from the nib with the view created in code, and does not add the latter to the view hierarchy (at least, not in the code included in the question).

Comment: Also, the assignment of `nil` is a red herring, since the questioner assigns an actual view in the same place immediately after. The assignment of `nil` may not even actually be included in the final build output by the compiler. Either assignment replaces the view from the nib.

Answer (score 1):

```
_mainWebView = [[MyWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
```

Above line of code tell that you create a new MyWebView, all hook up from IB will disconnect here.
And you can show it by:

```
[self.view addSubview:_mainWebView];
```

If you draw and hook up from IB, simply comment out init a new one

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue,

What my issue was, the web view that I placed on the storyboard is crossing the borders of the view controller.
When I pulled it back into the view controller it is working fine.